# HP Deskjet 3050 scanner always seems to break

Tags: windows-7, printer

I'm running a Windows 7 64 bit system, trying to use a network printer that came with the computer, to connect over a wireless network. Every time I try to use the scanner, after a reboot, the scanner doesn't work. I can always make it work, if I do the following:

1. Run the HP Scan Doctor utility.
2. When it can't detect the scanner, it will request that I uninstall the driver.
3. I uninstall the driver.
4. I re-install the driver, from the internet. It seems to detect the printer in the install, or I have to provide the IP address manually. Either way, it works.
5. Everything seems to work again.

This is extraordinarily annoying, not to mention I'm the only one in the house I would trust to do this, and other people want to use the printer from time to time. What could I do to make this work permanently?

Update: It might have something to do with my computer. It seems to work much better on another computer, windows 7 laptop. Not sure exactly what the deal is, but I'm still looking into it...

Comment: How do you use the scanner? I don't know if it's related but I've always used the scanner in the Deskjet 3050 through Paint Shop Pro

Comment: I usually use the HP Scan tool.

Answer (score 0):

You might try setting the HP scanner to a static IP address.  Zeroconf & Bonjour are supposed to provide address transparency, but my own system (similar setup) is much more reliable when the printer/scanner is locked down and doesn't move. (or potentially move).

Yes, DHCP generally *doesn't* move, since the DHCP server usually assigns a lease and doesn't change it, but '*phase-of-the-moon*' and other unexplainables can cause things to move in the address space, and suddenly it can't be found.

Dunno, give it a try.

Comment: The IP hasn't changed during all of this time. It's quite odd... Still, thanks for the idea...

Comment: Hmmm, try locking it down, then giving the driver the static IP, rather than letting it search for the scanner.